# A puzzle on an beginner's program

Tags: c++, memory

I wrote this dumb little program after watching about an hour of C++ tutorial.  It is garbage, but it produced a really weird error that a few software engineers haven't been able to solve, so now it's interesting to us.

It is supposed to spit out binomials and trinomials, and then give the derivative for the trinomials.  The dollar signs are there to help me copypasta into LaTeX.

EDIT: The exact error in the output is it's posting:
"inear equations do you need?-12x+8$"
instead of 
"Derivative= "

Thanks for the comment.

A /highfive for anyone who figures out why the output is so weird.

**The output:**

```
How many sets of 3 linear equations do you need?
2
How many sets of 3 quadratics do you need?
2
12x-3
-3x+12
-5x-9
15x-5
-5x+15
-4x-2
$8x^2-15x-6$
inear equations do you need?16x-15$
$-15x^2-6x+8$
inear equations do you need?-30x-6$
$-6x^28x-15$
inear equations do you need?-12x+8$
$2x^2-13x-2$
inear equations do you need?4x-13$
$-13x^2-2x+2$
inear equations do you need?-26x-2$
$-2x^22x-13$
inear equations do you need?-4x+2$
$11x^2-3x-13$
inear equations do you need?22x-3$
$-3x^2-13x+11$
inear equations do you need?-6x-13$
$-13x^211x-3$
inear equations do you need?-26x+11$
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**The Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
/*Simple Function maker*/
using namespace std;



void polynomial(string numberOfPolys)
{
    /*AX^2+BX+C format*/
    for (int i = 0; i <= (std::stoi(numberOfPolys, 0)); i++) {
        int a = (rand() % 15) + 1;
        int b = -1 * ((rand() % 15) + 1);
        int c = -1 * ((rand() % 15) + 1);
        int d = -1 * ((rand() % 15) + 1);
        string problemWriter = '$' + to_string(a) + 'x' + '^' + '2' + to_string(b) + 'x' + to_string(c) + '$';
        string problemWriter2 = '$' + to_string(b) + 'x' + '^' + '2' + to_string(c) + 'x' + '+' + to_string(a) + '$';
        string problemWriter3 = '$' + to_string(c) + 'x' + '^' + '2' + to_string(a) + 'x' + to_string(b) + '$';

        string answerWriter = "Derivative= " + '$' + to_string(a * 2) + 'x' + to_string(b) + '$';
        string answerWriter2 = "Derivative= " + '$' + to_string(b * 2) + 'x' + to_string(c) + '$';
        string answerWriter3 = "Derivative= " + '$' + to_string(c * 2) + 'x' + '+' + to_string(a) + '$';

        cout << problemWriter << endl;
        cout << answerWriter << endl;

        cout << problemWriter2 << endl;
        cout << answerWriter2 << endl;

        cout << problemWriter3 << endl;
        cout << answerWriter3 << endl;
    }

}


int main()
{   /*MX+B format*/


    string input;
    string polys;

    cout << "How many sets of 3 linear equations do you need?" << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "How many sets of 3 quadratics do you need?" << endl;
    getline(cin, polys);



    for (int i = 0; i < (std::stoi(input, 0)); i++) {
        int f = (rand() % 15) + 1;
        int g = -1 * ((rand() % 15) + 1);
        int h = -1 * ((rand() % 15) + 1);
        int k = -1 * (rand() % 15) + 1;
        string problemLWriter = to_string(f) + 'x' + to_string(g);
        string problemLWriter2 = to_string(g) + 'x' + '+' + to_string(f);
        string problemLWriter3 = to_string(h) + 'x' + to_string(k);
        cout << problemLWriter << endl;
        cout << problemLWriter2 << endl;
        cout << problemLWriter3 << endl;
    }
    polynomial(polys);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: *but it produced a really weird error that a few software engineers haven't been able to solve* you should say what the error is.

Comment: Thanks, edited with that info

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Hi Nathan, we actually did that using VS 2015, step by step.  Still can't explain the odd results.  One of the SW engi's said it seems like this string is "smashing the stack" which shouldn't be possible here, and I'm not going to pretend I know what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the lines when you create the `answerWriter` strings:

```
 string answerWriter = "Derivative= " + '$' + to_string(a * 2) + 'x' + to_string(b) + '$';
```

`"Derivative= "` is a character array, not a `string`. You cannot concatenate characters to it.

Change it to this:

```
string answerWriter = string("Derivative")+ '$' + to_string(a * 2) + 'x' + to_string(b) + '$';
```

Comment: Text in quotes is a text constant, which decays to a `char*` in most uses, including this.  Adding a char constant `'$'` to a `char*` advances the address.  It does not concatenate.  If either side of the addition is a string, you get concatenation, such as `"Derivative= " + ('$' + to_string(a * 2))`

Comment: @Andrea - it's not a char* but a character array, which then decays easily to a char* when a number - such as the ASCII code of the dollar symbol - is added to it.

Comment: Thanks Andrea and JSF!